# Hide a Kendo ui command column using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I can hide a regular column in Kendo UI...

```
var grid = $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.hideColumn("Id");
```

but I cannot seem to hide a command column such as this one...

```
columns.Command(command =>
{
command.Custom("Edit").Text("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"></span>").SendDataKeys(true).Click("ShowEditModal");
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the field property to your command column.

```
{ field: "coms", command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }
```

The hideColumn/showColumn actions use either the column number or column field "name".

[Kendo API Reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-hideColumn)

So, for example, using a button, you can do either:

```
                  $('#hide-col1').click(function () {
                var col = grid.columns[4];
                //var col = "coms";
                if (col.hidden) {
                    grid.showColumn(col);
                } else {
                    grid.hideColumn(col);
                }
              });
```

Or

```
                  $('#hide-col2').click(function () {
                grid.hideColumn("coms");
              });
```

Here's a working example: http://dojo.telerik.com/@nsnadell/uTeZu

If you wanted to only use the field property for a Show/Hide toggle, you'll need to put the field values in an array that has the same order as your columns and write a couple functions. But, not sure if that is a requirement for you.

Comment: How is this done with an MVC grid like the one specified in the original question?
I can't see a way to add a field value to the column in the MVC version